# Initialized priority variable in class and cpp core guidelines?

Tags: c++, oop, cpp-core-guidelines

I have use C++ Core Checker nuget and run my code analyst I have this warning

> ```
> warning C26495: Variable 'Point::_x' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable. (type.6:
> ```
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620422)

```
Point.h
class Point
{
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
public:
    Point();
    Point(int x, int y) :_x(x), _y(y) {}
    ~Point();

    void  setX(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
    void  setY(int y)
    {
        _y = y;
    }

    int getX()
    {
        return _x;
    }
    int getY()
    {
        return _y;
    }
}

Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point()
{
}


Point::~Point()
{
}
```

warning C26495: Variable 'Point::_x' is uninitialized. I fix the issue by make  _x = 0. is my fix is correct and match the guide?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. No, it does not match the guide, and it might not remove the warning. `Point::Point() : _x(0), _y(0)` is how you initialize member variables. (For ints it's the same as `_x = 0; _y = 0;` but for other types it might not be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++11 standard your fix is a valid solution.

from the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) article:

> Member initialization

Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:

1) In the member initializer list of the constructor.

```
struct S
{
    int n;
    std::string s;
    S() : n(7) // direct-initializes n, default-initializes s
    { }
};
```

2) Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration, which is used if the member is omitted in the member initializer list

```
struct S
{
    int n = 7;
    std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    S() // copy-initializes n, list-initializes s
    { }
};
```

And your solution uses the equals initializer used in 2)

Answer (score 0):

Choose between these two options:

1) in-class initialization (preferred, default constructor can be defaulted)

```
class Point
{
private:
    int _x{};
    int _y{};
public:
    Point() = default;
...
};
```

2) delegating constructor (default constructor delegates to the one taking x and y)

```
class Point
{
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
public:
    Point() : Point(0, 0) {}
...
};
```

Option 1 is preferrable because you only write all defaults once, not in every constructor. This might not be a difference in your small class but it makes a difference if you have more constructors taking different arguments.